# Простые люди — какие они?

Tags: лексика

После революции  у нас были отменены **«простолюдины»**, но, кажется, сразу же появились **«простые люди»**, существующие до сих пор. **А каково значение этого слова в современном обществе?**

Эти люди обыкновенные, заурядные, посредственные, без особых способностей?    Или никому не известные,  без публичного имени?  Может быть,  профессия у них непрестижная или доход низкий?  Или им приходится зарабатывать на хлеб насущный,  а праздное существование  недоступно?  И вообще, э**то своеобразное сословие или просто личные качества**  людей (образование, образ жизни, духовные запросы)?

Кроме того, в словаре не указано  еще одно  **(позитивное!) значение слова**: простые, хорошие, симпатичные люди.

А вот еще интересное «откровение»: Вконец опустившийся аристократ или взобравшийся на вершины власти и богатства простолюдин всё равно останутся бывшим аристократом и бывшим простолюдином. [Денис Драгунский. Матрица // «Частный корреспондент», 2010]

**Так кого же мы называем простыми людьми?**

**ПРОСТОНАРОДЬЕ**,  собир. **Ист**. Люди, принадлежащие к непривилегированным сословиям, классам; простой народ. Выйти из простонародья.

**ПРОСТОЛЮДИН**, -**Ист**. Человек, принадлежащий к непривилегированным сословиям, классам (крестьянин, рабочий, мещанин). Выйти из простолюдинов. Говорил и одевался, как п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы выделил два основных значения.

- Обыкновенные люди. Говорящий сравнивает в своей речи кого-либо с "простыми людьми" из народа. Простым людям в этой оппозиции мысленно противоставляется элита - культурная, властная и т.п.
- Отсутствие сложной духовной структуры, часто - как саморефлексия говорящего и часть самоидентификации.

Кстати, социологи говорят о том, что существует четыре разные России, поэтому простых людей (читай: обыкновенных) не привести к единому знаменателю, это будет как минимум четыре разных жизненных уклада.

Comment: @Sibylla вопрос хороший :) но слишком выдаётся за рамки лексического определения. А есть ещё поговорка: простота хуже воровства.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.   А вот вариант "простой человек - это хороший человек" насколько распространен? Это, кажется, "открытый, откровенный, бесхитростный, прямой; не церемонный". И как соотносятся "хорошие" простые люди с "плохими"  - недалёкими по уму, глуповатыми, наивными. Да и  много ли у нас их осталось -"хороших" простых людей?